# NodeJS consumir funciones que tiene de parametros (res, req) desde otro archivo.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

tengo el siguiente problema, que me parece que es muy simple, pero soy muy nuevo en node, entonces aún tengo problemas con estas cosas.

Tengo un archivo .js que se conecta a un servicio externo y hace uso del (res y req) y lo retorna como json.

Lo que necesito es retornar ese resultado dentro de una variable en otro archivo .js

Les dejo un ejemplo para que me entiendan.

```
    export function getConversation( req, res) {
  //  Getting workspace credentials from mongo
  //connectToConversation('req.body.conversationName');
  //console.log(input);
  connectToConversation('Courtesy'); //Business
  conversation = new Conversation({
    username: CurrentConversation[0]['username'],
    password: CurrentConversation[0]['password'],
    url: '',
    version_date: 
  });
  console.log(req.body.context);
  var workspace = CurrentConversation[0]['workspaceID'];
  //var workspace = '';
  if (!workspace) {
    return res.json({
      'output': {
        'text': ''
      }
    });
  }
  console.log(CurrentConversation[0]['workspaceID']);
  var payload = {
    workspace_id: workspace,
    input: req.body.input || {}
  };


  conversation.message(payload, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code  || 500).json(err);
    }
    return res.json(updateMessage(payload, data));
  });
}
```

Yo necesito hacer uso de esa funcion desde otro archivo.js y enviarle el resultado a la misma.

Se que el problema es simple, perdon por molestar.

Gracias.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es en un archivo donde haces la rutas recibes los parámetros req y res y desde otro archivo hacer la funcionalidad?

Comment: si, exacto. Eso mismo

Comment: https://expressjs.com/es/guide/writing-middleware.html

Answer (score 0):

yo le tengo en una carpeta llamado router y esto es un ejemplo como lo tengo:

router.js

```
var express = require("express");
var passport = require("passport");
var contenido = require("./contenido");

var router=express.Router();

//Así directamente
router.get("/menu/todos",contenido.mostrartodos);

//o de esta forma 
router.get("/menu/todos", function (req,res) {
  contenido.mostrartodos (req, function (result) {
    res.json(result);
  })
})
```

contenido.js

```
//Así directamente
module.exports.mostrartodos = function (req, res) {
  res.json({result: 'resultado'});
}

//o de esta forma

module.exports.mostrartodos = function (req, callback) {
  var resutl = {
    result: 'resultado'
  }
  callback(result);
}
```

Comment: Si quieres usar el router en el app.js tienes que exportar el router, `module.exports = router;` (en el router.js) y en el app.js requerirlo y luego con utilizar express para usarlo. **Ej**: `app.use("/", router);` Esto es importante y siempre lo olvidan, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

como estas? te dejo la siguiente solución, puedes crear 2 controladores en un archivo JS, una para utilizarlo en las rutas principales, y la otra en cualquier archivo JS que quieras utilizándolo como una función.

**ejemplo.js**

```
const ctrl = {}; // Estos son controladores
const functions = {}; // Estos son controladores

functions.get = ({ data }) => { // Usando el Destructuring si lo deseas
  // Aquí escribe el código que necesites utilizar en otro archivo js
  return { data }; // Debes retornar para que te devuelva el valor deseado
};

ctrl.get = (req, res) => { // A ctrl le asignamos una misión por medio de las propiedades de los objectos le decimos que recuerde esta función que le colocamos por nombre get, igualmente hicimos con functions
  const result = functions.get(req.body); // llamando la función de arriba por medio de un controlador, esto lo puedes colocar con async/await depende de lo que necesites
  return res.send(result); // Envias el resultado al frontend

  // Edita esto a tu gusto
};

module.exports = { ctrl, functions }; // Exportamos por defectos los controladores
```

**route.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const contenido = require("./ejemplo"); // Este es el archivo que tiene los controladores

var router = express.Router();

router.get("/obtener/contenido", contenido.ctrl.get); // Accedemos a ctrl para nuestro controladores de rutas y accedemos a la propiedad get para ejecutar la función, en las rutas esto se activa de modo automático cuando escucha una llamada a la api
```

**archivosJSAleatorioDondeLoNecesitesMyFriend.js**

```
const contenido = require("./ejemplo"); // Este es el archivo que tiene los controladores

// Para acceder a la función solo tienes que llamar functions que es la que tiene obviamente las funciones por eso la llamamos functions

// AQUI ESCRIBE LA LOGICA

const respuesta = contenido.functions.get(parametros) // Y así ejecutas la función, no tendrás problemas de código sucio o espagueti.
```